# Issue with the c# script for player climb in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the player to climb a ladder. (2D game)

I used this code for that,

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider){
    if(collider.gameObject.tag=="Ladder"){
        _canClimb = true;
        _anim.SetBool("Climb",true);
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider){
    if(collider.gameObject.tag=="Ladder"){
        _canClimb = false;
        _anim.SetBool("Climb",false);
    }
}
```

In the update() ,

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && _canClimb == true){
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,ladderTop.transform.position,Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I have put a child game object to ladder to get the position of the top of the ladder.

But When the player jumps and hit with the box collider of the ladder I can see the climbing animation. And after that the player falls down to the ground again. It doesn't move up. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working as I expected, Here is the code,

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && _canClimb == true){
        _myRigidBody.isKinematic = true;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,ladderTop.transform.position,Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I just added this line and it works perfectly :

_myRigidBody.isKinematic = true;

[Rigidbody.isKinematic](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html)

> If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore.